# OpenAL Invalid Operation

Tags: openal

I'm getting an OpenAL "Invalid Operation" error when trying to delete a buffer.
I've checked with alIsBuffer and alIsSource that my source and buffer are valid OpenAL objects, and that's the case.

```
    assert(alIsBuffer(m_buffer) == AL_TRUE);
    assert(alIsSource(m_source) == AL_TRUE);

    alErrorChecking(alSourcei(m_source, AL_BUFFER, NULL));
    alErrorChecking(alDeleteBuffers(1, &m_buffer)); //Here i'm getting the Invalid Operation error
    m_buffer = 0;
```

Comment: I simply fixed it by deleting the source first, then the buffer, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to shut down OpenAL

```
ALenum errorCode = 0;

// Stop the sources
alSourceStopv(1, & streaming_source[0]);        //      streaming_source

// Clean-up
alDeleteSources(1, &streaming_source[0]);
alDeleteBuffers(16, &streaming_source[0]);
errorCode = alGetError();
alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
errorCode = alGetError();
alcDestroyContext(openal_output_context);
alcCloseDevice(openal_output_device);
```

where in my header I have

```
#include  <AL/al.h>
#include  <AL/alc.h>

ALuint streaming_source[1];

ALCdevice * openal_output_device;
ALCcontext * openal_output_context;
```

Answer (score 1):

The buffer can't be attached to a source.
Assuming that `m_buffer` is playing on `m_source`, you need this line before your delete the buffer:

```
alSourceUnqueueBuffers( m_source, 1, &m_buffer);
```